# Tikz package. Plot a segment centered in one point

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to plot a segment centered in one point? I need to give the point and the length only.

Comment: Please see my comment on your random-set question. Again, perhaps this has a specific meaning to you, but to me it doesn't. In any case, questions should (very nearly almost always) include a minimal document setting up the problem and showing us what difficulty you're having. That way, you're much more likely to get useful answers. Right now, I suspect you're just posting these questions as a twisted form of practical joke, to be honest. They're too vague to be asked, never mind answered.

Comment: you also need to give angle or is it horizontal?

Comment: @percusse Yes, with an angle is better! Thank you and sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `insert path` key.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[s/.style 2 args={insert path={+(#1:{0.5*#2})--+(180+#1:{0.5*#2})}}]
\draw[style=help lines] (-2,-2) grid[step=1] (2,2);

\draw[thick] (0,0)  [s={45}{2*sqrt(2)}] 
             (-1,1) [s={90}{2}]
             (1,-1) [s={240}{1}]
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]